# Using nested "for" loops to produce results in a formatted table in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I was wondering if someone could help me in write a program that calculates the sale prices for items normally priced
from $9.95 to $49.95, where the sale price can be 5% to 50% off. Display
the results in an appropriately formatted table.

I have done this

```
price = [9.95, 14.95, 19.95, 24.95, 29.95, 34.95, 39.95, 44.95, 49.95]
discount = range(5, 51, 5)
for i in discount:
    K = 1 - (i/100)
    for j in price:
        P = j * K
        V ="{:.2f}".format(P)
        C ='{:>7}'.format(V)
        print(C, end=" ")
    print()
```

which gives

```
    9.45   14.20   18.95   23.70   28.45   33.20   37.95   42.70   47.45 
    8.96   13.46   17.95   22.45   26.95   31.46   35.96   40.46   44.96 
    8.46   12.71   16.96   21.21   25.46   29.71   33.96   38.21   42.46 
    7.96   11.96   15.96   19.96   23.96   27.96   31.96   35.96   39.96 
    7.46   11.21   14.96   18.71   22.46   26.21   29.96   33.71   37.46 
    6.96   10.46   13.96   17.46   20.96   24.46   27.96   31.46   34.96 
    6.47    9.72   12.97   16.22   19.47   22.72   25.97   29.22   32.47 
    5.97    8.97   11.97   14.97   17.97   20.97   23.97   26.97   29.97 
    5.47    8.22   10.97   13.72   16.47   19.22   21.97   24.72   27.47 
    4.97    7.47    9.97   12.47   14.97   17.48   19.98   22.48   24.98
```

but i need it to look like this

```
Normal p ri c e :    $9 . 9 5  $14 . 9 5  $19 . 9 5  $24 . 9 5  $29 . 9 5  $34 . 9 5  $39 . 9 5  $44 . 9 5  $49 . 9 5
         %o f f : 5%  9 . 4 5  1 4 . 2 0  1 8 . 9 5  2 3 . 7 0  2 8 . 4 5  3 3 . 2 0  3 7 . 9 5  4 2 . 7 0  4 7 . 4 5
         %o f f : 10%  8 . 9 6  1 3 . 4 6  1 7 . 9 5  2 2 . 4 5  2 6 . 9 5  3 1 . 4 6  3 5 . 9 6  4 0 . 4 6  4 4 . 9 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an inline if statement with the print to prepend the column that labels it:

```
price = [9.95, 14.95, 19.95, 24.95, 29.95, 34.95, 39.95, 44.95, 49.95]
discount = range(0, 51, 5)
for i in discount:
    K = 1 - (i/100)
    for j in price:
        P = j * K
        V ="${:.2f}".format(P)
        C ='{:>7}'.format(V)
        print("o f f : " +str(i) + "%" if i else "Normal P r i c e : " if j else "", str(C).replace("."," . "), end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use following snippet

```
price = [9.95, 14.95, 19.95, 24.95, 29.95, 34.95, 39.95, 44.95, 49.95]
discount = range(5, 51, 5)
row_format = "{:>15}" * (len(price) + 1)
print(row_format.format("Normal price:", *price))
for d in discount:
    K = 1 - (float(d)/100)
    prices_adj = [p*K for p in price]
    print(row_format.format("{} %  off:".format(d), *prices_adj))
```

Or look at some packages like [PrettyTable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable), [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) or [texttable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/texttable).